# Routing in SilverStripe using regex

Tags: php, regex, silverstripe

In SilverStripe I want to create dynamic routing. What I am trying to route is every url that matches the following pattern: some numbers and text separated with dashes and at the end "-tx-i-numberid"

Example: 
`http://example.com/some-text-and-numbers-separated-with-dashes-tx-i1654766`

I've read this [documentation](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/controllers/routing/) and I couldn't figure it out.

I would like to have some rule like the following

```
'$Slug-tx-i$ID' : 'TeamController'
```

I wonder if I can do it using regex, or some other way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do this with regex from within the routing system. Your best bet is to match '$Slug' and then parse it in the controller.

If your controller action instantiates a second controller and passes on the request, you can actually nest controllers (See for a more in depth example https://vimeo.com/album/3629143/video/143149869).

For example:

```
class Controller1 extends Controller
{
    private static $allowed_actions = ['index'];
    public function index($req) {
        if (preg_match('/myregex/', $req->param('Slug'))) {
            return Controller2::create()->handleAction($request, $this->model);
        } else {
            return Controller3::create()->handleAction($request, $this->model);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using .htaccess could be a possibility for this too?

Comment: @DanHensby I tried the following `public function index($request)
    {
        if ($passed_regex) {
            return MatchedPage_Controller::create()->handleRequest($request, $this->model);
        } else {
             // I want here to handle all other urls  to match how there are created in the cms . For example I have /contact-us  
        }
    }`
when it pass the regex, It's working fine, I am just not sure what write for the else to handle all the other requests, so they can match their controllers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
public function index($request)
{
    $url = $request->param('Slug');
    $matches = array();
    if (strpos($url, '/') === false && preg_match('/^[a-z\-]+\-i([0-9]+)/i', $url, $matches)) {
        return "matched " . var_export($matches, true);
    }
    return ContentController::create()->handleRequest($request, $this->model);
}
```

But you have to change the routing rules and I haven't figured out how to get that working without hijacking ALL URLs.

Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do? Perhaps could solve this another way.

What about:

```
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z\-]+\-i([0-9]+) /custom/$1
```

in the .htaccess? (It's untestested, but means you can more accurately target the pages).

Perhaps it's a 301 map and you're really looking for instead?

Comment: I could write the following code which very similar to the code you suggested `public function index($request) { if ($passed_regex) { return MatchedPage_Controller::create()->handleRequest($request, $this->model); } else {   } }` Now I can detect my pattern urls with regexp and handle it to the right controller. But the problem when the slug doesn't match the pattern, for example: http://example.com/admin, the slug param will be 'admin' it will not match the regexp, then a blank page will be displayed. I want some code in the else that continue handling non matching urls to their controller

Comment: It's not just about admin, actually any url slug for a page that I already created from the cms, and comes directly after the site name, for example: http://example.com/contact-us

Comment: Hmm. This is generally a really bad approach. I think you'd have to customise director to really get this going. I've asked for more info on what the actual use case is here. Why you need to use this url format. Can I have it?

Comment: Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95752/discussion-between-kamal-and-dan-hensby).